# Handbrake ps1 script using all my computers memory

Tags: memory, powershell, handbrake

I've been recently using a powershell script for handbrake, encoding mkv's to smaller mp4's and have been doing it successfully for several months. For some reason though, when I run the script after several hours, my computer runs really slow to the point where I would have to restart it while it's in the middle of doing so. I do now that it has been happening from the last Windows 10 update but I haven't done anything differently lately to have it happened. Any ideas on what could have happened.

Comment: while i can't help much, you can help yourself by including the bare bones of your script AND what happens before things start bogging down. does it get slow after finishing a single file, several files ... details like that would help those who are good at this sort of thing help you. [*grin*]

Comment: Sure, here's the script I use for handbrake https://pastebin.com/raw/JZyZv6De

Comment: while i see lots of oddities  [*grin*], i don't see anything glaringly wrong. have you tried watching task manager to see if something is eating up resources? perhaps the repeated calls to handbrake are leaving "stuff" in RAM? maybe adding a few seconds between each call to handbrake would help?

Comment: How would I do that, I'm not really up to date on powershell coding

Comment: i presume "how would it do that" is about the pause idea. [*grin*] add a `Start-Sleep -Seconds 5` right after your `move-item -Path` line so that there is a 5 second pause after each file is finished.